# Show that this function has to be constant

Tags: general-topology

Show that if $f:([0,1],\tau_e) \rightarrow (\mathbb{R},\tau(\mathbb{B})$ is a continuous function, then $f$ is constant.

$\mathbb{B}=$ { [a,b): a < b}

Proof.:

I got the idea: I have to show that if I take an open set in $(\mathbb{R},\tau(\mathbb{B})$ and $f$ is not constant, then $f^{-1}(U) \notin \tau_e$. For instance, if I take $U=[0,1)$, I got that $f^{-1}(U)=[a,b)$ for some $a,b \in [0,1]$, which is not open in the standard topology.

So I wanted to show that if I take a function $f$ such as $f(t)=c, \forall t \in [0,1]$, then $f^{-1}({c})$ is an open set in the standard topology.

But the element {c}... is not open in $\tau(\mathbb{B})$, right? I can't obtain it as finite intersection of open sets or arbitrary union of open sets...

And $f^{-1}(c)=[0,1]$...which is a closed set on the standard topology... so it seems that $f$ is not continuous... what am I missing?

Comment: $t_e$ is the euclidian topology

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what you are missing, but here's an easy solution:

$(\mathbb{R}, \tau(\mathbb{B}))$ is totally disconnected. Indeed, assume that $A\subseteq\mathbb{R}$ is a subset with at least two distinct points, say $x,y\in A$. Assume that $x<y$ and pick a point $x<c<y$. Then $(-\infty, c)$ and $[c, \infty)$ are both open in $(\mathbb{R}, \tau(\mathbb{B}))$ and they "split" $A$ into two open, nonempty, disjoin subsets. Therefore $A$ is not connected. In particular only points are connected in $(\mathbb{R}, \tau(\mathbb{B}))$.

Now since $[0,1]$ with its Euclidean topology is connected, then...?

Comment: ...then if $[0,1]$ is connected, and $f$ continuos $=> f([0,1])$ is connected: but the only connected sets in $(ℝ,τ())$ are the points ${c}$. So $f$ has to be constant.

Comment: Is it correct? 

Is there a way to proof it without using compactness?

Comment: Yes, this is correct. As for the other question: you mean "connectness". I don't know. Probably yeah.

Comment: Thanks a lot! ;)

Comment: You don't need to use $c$ between $x$ and $y$. If $x<y$ then $(-\infty,y) $ and $ [y,\infty)$ are open in $\tau (\mathbb B)$.